# Meteor updating/removing/inserting documents. Client or server side?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

Which way is the most efficient and safe to make changes to mongoDB?
UPD: allow/deny rules on the client VS server method calls

Comment: Are you thinking allow/deny rules VS method calls?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What do you mean with "client or server side"? And the @PeppeL-G question is correct! : )

Comment: @PeppeL-G, yes, that's right. Sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side. Else your users can see what database you're using. You don't want that.